# Replace the values in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataset in which I have four columns. I want to replace the values (1's and 2's) in **survival_status** column into (Negative and Postive). I am using the pandas to change the values.

```
 Age  operation_year  axillary_nodes_detected  survival_status
0   30              64                        1                1
1   30              62                        3                1
2   30              65                        0                2
3   31              59                        2                1
4   31              65                        4                2

Haberman["survival_status"] = Haberman["survival_status"].apply(lambda x : 'Positive' if x == 2 else 'Negative')
```

After applying that, It is changing the entire column values to Negative.

```
Haberman['survival_status'].value_counts()
Negative    306
Name: survival_status, dtype: int64
```

Could anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a dictionary mapping. But first make sure your dataframe is converted to `int`:

```
df = df.astype(int)

d = {2: 'Positive', 1: 'Negative'}

df['survival_status'] = df['survival_status'].map(d)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Age  operation_year  axillary_nodes_detected survival_status
0   30              64                        1        Negative
1   30              62                        3        Negative
2   30              65                        0        Positive
3   31              59                        2        Negative
4   31              65                        4        Positive
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and convert column to `integer` first:

```
Haberman["survival_status"] = np.where(Haberman["survival_status"].astype(int) == 2,
                                       'Positive','Negative')
```

Comment: it is giving ` TypeError: invalid type comparison`

Comment: @merklexy - Can you check solution now?